# How to test UI in different iOS version - iOS UI Testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am designing an UI component library.

For certain design requirement, I need to make different implementation by checking the iOS version as the lower version might not support the latest syntax/feature.

There are a few methods in my library which are trying to do

```
func designSth(){
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      //implement sth support for iOS 10 and above
   }else{
      //implement sth for device below iOS 10
   }
}
```

However when I write the UI test cases, it will always cover the iOS 10 and above but not cover the iOS 10 and below.

Is there a way to set target simulator iOS version in UI testing script?
Such like `XCUIApplication`, `XCUIElement` which is able to configure in `setUp()` in UI testing script.

Comment: Can't you simply pick the simulator with desired iOS version and run tests on it? Are you running your tests manually within Xcode or automatically by CI?

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec I am running my UI tests within Xcode. Do you mean that i select desired version of simulator? If I using this way, I believe that the coverage will be always reflect one side of code, either above iOS10 or below iOS10.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But with the new Xcode 10.3 you could generate two reports for two different iOS versions and then merge the reports with new xccov command line tool. See `xcrun xccov` for examples. I didn't have a chance to verify if it's what you need though. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check iOS version in UI test using
`let iOSVersion = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion.majorVersion`
then wrap your test definition around the iOSVersion check